# How can I use my own authentication mechanism but leverage ASP.NET MVC authorization?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication

I have an existing user accounts db from another (non-MVC) project and it's a requirement for now that we use our specific authentication process to register / log in. But I'd like to use MVC for authorization.  Can you please let me know how I can accomplish this?

Comment: just ask the user for their uname/password and compare it to the db then set the forms.authenticated to true (not in front of a pc right now so I'm not sure if that's the correct function)

Answer (score 1):

You should implement a custom membership provider. Many of the methods of the membership provider don't need to be implemented, so you can just implement the methods you need (i.e., authentication or roles, but not registration, password changing). You can model your custom membership provider to your existing database. [See this blog post](http://www.danharman.net/2011/06/23/asp-net-mvc-3-custom-membership-provider-with-repository-injection/) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

We're currently looking at something similar, and are investigating using [ServiceStack](http://www.servicestack.net/) - specifically the [authentication and authorization](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Authentication-and-authorization) interface they provide. However, we've only just started researching this so can't advise how suitable it is.